# Remove disabled attribute/state during submission

Tags: 8, webforms

I would like to find a way to remove the `disabled` attribute from webform fields inside a **custom Handler**.

The `disabled` attribute is currently being applied to webform elements during user input via `conditions/states` with the UI and I would like to remove this attribute after clicking submit so that these webform fields will submit their values.

I've been looking through the available functions from the `WebformhandlerBase`: https://git.uwaterloo.ca/drupal-org/webform/blob/8.x-5.9/src/Plugin/WebformHandlerBase.php, but can't find where this attribute exists, and don't see an approach to alter/remove it.

`public function validateForm() {}` seems like a good moment in time to alter, but I can't find this attribute.

Noting I have success doing this with jQuery but would prefer doing this in my custom Handler

How do you remove a form field attribute (`disabled`) with a custom Handler after a user clicks submit?

Comment: And you are definitely not looking for the `Clear value(s) when hidden` checkbox every element has under its "Conditions" tab and uncheck that, or are you?

Comment: Hey @leymannx, I don’t think so. I need the field values, but as the field is both required, and disabled as a user fills in the form, I need to remove the disabled attribute so form submit completes

Answer (score 0):

Once you submit a form, you are not able to retrieve disabled inputs (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#constructing-the-form-data-set). That said:

- You cannot modify input's attributes from server-side since the submission data is already posted.
- Developing your solution with jQuery on `.submit()` function is a good idea (far away from bad practices).
- You can also make another work around: instead of disabling you could use readonly="readonly" attribute (https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40-971218/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.2)

Comment: Is that true for the validateForm() function? I see that with the field both required and disabled, the form does not submit and is set with an error message.

Comment: validateForm() makes use of the submitted values. Because you have disabled a field and is not present in the submitted values, that means will not be present in the validateForm() either.

If your form is showing an error, check webform_hooks validations along with the webform UI in case you have implementation other validations.

Comment: @Prestosaurus did you find an answer on how to identify and remove disabled fields in the handler, if so could you please share it. thanks

Comment: Hi @amit, I did not and had to take a different approach

Comment: @Prestosaurus we have found a workaround, its a bit tedious but works as a proof of concept. I posted it as answer, hopefully the moderator would reinstate my deleted post.

Comment: @Prestosaurus added a workaround as an answer, we are hoping to publish a recipe to the webform module with an example form yaml and sample custom handler.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround that seems to work, for example

1. Create a number element with key as num_a
   2.Create a hidden checkbox element with its key as num_a_ignore
2. Add a condition to num_a element in #1 to turn on the checkbox when value or num_a is say greater than 10
3. Write a custom handler which probes for *_ignore keys and
   matches them with any element keys. When a match is found and the
   value of *_ignore key is true that element is disabled and processed
   accordingly.